# Cut string away from url in javascript

Tags: javascript, split, substring

There is a string like below

```
var indicator = -45(www.anyweb.com)
```

the number -45 can be any number. How can I take out only the -45 separately in javascript? Assume the format will always be like this

```
number(url)
```

Comment: With `parseInt(indicator)` if you want an integer and `parseFloat(indicator)` if you want a 'float'

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `parseInt`. As the (mozilla) docs say:

> If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the
>   specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and
>   returns the integer value parsed up to that point.

That means: if the first part looks like a number, it gets converted and the rest is thrown away.

`parseInt("-24(foo.com)")`
gives
`-24`

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
indicator = indicator.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
```

or

```
indicator = indicator.replace(/\d+/g, '');
```

If you are looking to just get the numbers then try something like this:

```
indicator = indicator.match(/[0-9]+/g);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that get rid of the number? I think they want the number without the URL.

Comment: @MikeC I read that wrong then. I thought take out number meant removing the number from the url.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is an actual string (i.e. wrapped in quotes), you could strip the number out via a simple regular expression, which would check if the beginning of the string started with a number :

```
// Your original string
var indicator = "-45(www.anyweb.com)";
// Access your number
var number = indicator.match(/^\-?\d+/)[0];  // yields "-45"
// Now remove it from your original string
indicator = indicator.replace(/^\-?\d+/,''); // yields "(www.anyweb.com)"
```

**Example**

```js
// Your original string
var indicator = "-45(www.anyweb.com)";
// Access your number
var number = indicator.match(/^\-?\d+/)[0];
// Now remove it from your original string
indicator = indicator.replace(/^\-?\d+/,'');
console.log('indicator: ' + indicator + ', number: ' + number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method and take the first element from the array:

```
var indicator = "-45(www.anyweb.com)";
var fubar = indicator.split("(");
console.log(fubar[0]); // returns   >> "-45"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12534405)

Comment: @CarlMarkham better now?